# Autolayout few buttons with equal spacing and fixed width

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to use AutoLayout constraints to automatically reposition buttons frame.

Scenario : There are 5 UIButtons and which needs to be equally aligned.

1. Expected and Achieved (Shown via images in google drive ) : [Images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5iOdFgW5AfiYXVnT1ppOTg3TW8&authuser=0)
2. What I have used :

   ```
     First Button added the constraint top,left and buttom.
     For last button added constraint right,top and bottom.
     For rest button added top and bottom Constraint
     Then added horizontal spacing between Buttons
     Then added fixed width
   ```

I have shared the project for the reference : [Project](https://drive.google.com/a/jifflenow.com/file/d/0B5iOdFgW5AfiWGtGc19Lcy1FanM/view)

Please do let me know where is the issue in the horizontal spacing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the fixed width constraint. You are giving constraints ambiguously. If you are giving horizontal spacing means, you need to compromise on width of the button. Or else, if you want fixed width for buttons means, you need to compromise on horizontal spacing which is not required.

Comment: I did that also, but same issue.Did you downloaded the project ?

Comment: please provide your email. I will email your code. which I modified.

Comment: can u send me code to anilchopram@gmail.com, let me check it

Comment: Proposed solution not working when changed to different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

1.Make first button Equal width to Superview (Say if width of superview is 100px set multiplier of Equal width Constraint to 0.15,so button with will be 15px and you extra 25px for space between buttons).

2.Add a constraint programatically relating first button width and first button height(Say if u what height button to 25% of width like that).

3.Make all other buttons with Equal Width ,Equal height to First Button

4.Then add trailing space of First button to container

5.Then add horizontal spacing between each button to some constant

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give leading, trailing and equal-widths constraints between adjacent buttons.
Check my answer here, I've explained with screenshots and steps to achieve this:
[What is the best approach for horizontally aligning 5 buttons with Autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054139/what-is-the-best-approach-for-horizontally-aligning-5-buttons-with-autolayout/34062425#34062425)
Hope it helps! :)